# unbound method createDataFrame()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am facing error when trying to create a DataFrame from an RDD.
**My code:**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark import sql


conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('local')
conf.setAppName('Test')
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
print sc.version

rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)])

df = sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score"]).collect()

print df
```

**Error:**

```
df = sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score"]).collect()
TypeError: unbound method createDataFrame() must be called with SQLContext 
           instance as first argument (got RDD instance instead)
```

I accomplished the same task in spark shell where a straight forward last three lines of code will print the values. I mainly suspect the import statements because that is where the difference comes between IDE and Shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use an instance of SQLContext. So you could try something like the following:

```
sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score"]).collect()
```

More details in [pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext).